# Training a neural network model in neuralnet package in R taking days and not finished yet

Tags: r, neural-network, model, multiclass-classification

I have constructed a model in R (R Studio) for a neural network with two hidden layers using the neuralnet package. It is already 3 non-stop days but the model is not trained. All I see is the usual blinking cursor which is the sign of data in processing. There are no error or warning messages and nothing has crashed. All I need to know is if this is normal and how long I should expect before the model is trained and the object is created.

This is a relatively simple model with 1260 rows and 11 columns of continuous data as features predicting the 12th column ('labels') as a factor with six classes (multi-class classification task). Data has been properly scaled before splitting it to train and test datasets and the factor column of classes has been re-coded to numeric values with the revalue() in R. Here are the model specs:

```
 model = neuralnet(
        labels~A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K,        
    data=train_data,
    hidden=c(4,2),                
    linear.output = FALSE,       
    stepmax = 1e+06,             

    )
```

I have read many online posts including a number of Stack Overflow questions of similar nature but none gives me the answer I need. Is this caused by GPU or the complexity of the model? and how may I solve this issue? Here are my machine's specs:

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 64 bit, RAM 48 GiB, processor AMD® Ryzen 5 2600 six-core processor × 12.

I can provide more information about the code and my machine if needed. I would appreciate it if anyone could help out.

Edit: Someone from the discussion suggested that I add more details about my code, so here are the pre-processing parts:

```
#revalue the labels:

data <- 
data %>%
mutate(labels = revalue(labels, c("label1" = 1, "label2" = 2, 
"label3" = 3, "label4" = 4, "label5" = 5, "label6" = 6)))

#scaling numeric columns
varnames<- c("labels")
index<- names(data) %in% varnames
data1<- scale(data[, !index])  
data = merge(data["labels"] ,data1)

# split training and testing datasets
train_idx <- sample(nrow(data), 0.7 * nrow(data))
train_data <- data[train_idx,]
test_data <- data[-train_idx,] 
data <- data %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

#here the above model is run
```

Comment: @Phil: May I ask why you demoted my question? You have not commented on it.

Comment: I didn't demote your question, I removed the rstudio tag because it is not relevant to your question.

Comment: @Phil: Thanks for clarifying it (and for the edit).

Comment: I have also faced this problem with some datasets. It would be great if you could post the dataset so the problem becomes reproducible. You can also raise an issue [here](https://github.com/bips-hb/neuralnet/issues).

Comment: @UseR10085: Thanks for the comment. I have used my own collected data; I'm afraid you may not reproduce my exact problem, but if you and (as it seems) many others have the same problem with the neuralnet package, then it's not the issue with our code or machine spec, and perhaps we should report this to the package maintainers. I managed to build the same model with keras in Python via Jupyter and it gave results within a minute.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very small network, a small dataset; it shouldn't take that long. On top of that your specs are good enough. My suggestion is that you run an example from the documentation first to see if you can get it running properly. One of the examples from the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf):

```
library(neuralnet)
# Binary classification
nn <- neuralnet(Species == "setosa" ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris, linear.output = FALSE)
## Not run: print(nn)
## Not run: plot(nn)
```

Then go back to your code. One hour is already too much, so if that happens again just try to subsample your dataset. If it keeps happening, maybe there is some configuration you need to do on your linux machine.

Edit after question update: the `merge` command you used will [Merge two data frames by common columns or row names](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/merge), so my guess is that you are adding a lot of rows here. If I do the same with iris data set, the number of rows go from 150 to 22500. You can instead convert to data frame after scaling and use a simple bracket notation instead of merge:

```
> data1<- as.data.frame(scale(data[, !index]))
> data1['labels']=data['labels']
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It turned out my machine is fine and so is the model. I think there's something wrong with the neuralnet package in R; I noticed it has added around a million rows to my data; I don't understand why and how, but I'm sure my model and all code before it is correct. If you happen to test any data with neuralnet package, could you please report here if similar issues are faced? Thanks

Comment: That's odd. Maybe the data is not in the right format, but from your post, the pre-processing seems okay. I tried the example in my answer, and everything looks fine. Can you provide the dataset or give more details about the code itself?

Comment: Thanks for the further suggestions. Given the issues, I turned to Python and Keras and the model with similar specs was constructed in less than a minute in Jupyter. Even though I received low accuracy, at least I know there's nothing wrong with the model and code. I will add more details about the code in the body of my question above. Thanks again.

Comment: @MaryamNasseri Updated answer. I guess you shouldn't merge like that

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion that you've added above. I'll do that. Btw, I did notice that there are many more rows added. Thanks for pointing it out.